# Validity of Press-Schechter formalism at the end of recombination

Tags: cosmology, structure-formation

I was wondering if Press-Schechter formalism on Spherical collapse is applicable sometime at the end of recombination, i.e. the photons have started to free stream but the free streaming length is still not the horizon size?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here. PS formalism is generally applied to the dark matter field, not the radiation/plasma field. Are you asking if we could have another similar formalism for radiation?